# Android: How to center crop images without scaling

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview, crop

I have some images I want to show in thumbnails, and I want them to center crop and not scale. The images themselves are almost always rectangular, and I want to crop them around their center and have them fit into a square ImageView. The bitmaps themselves either have a height that matches the size of the ImageView, or a width that matches. So essentially I just want to crop off the left/right or the top/bottom of each photo, and not lose any quality.

When I try to use `ScaleType.CENTER_CROP` my images are becoming blurry. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should just use ScaleType.CENTER. This will perform no scaling, it will just center the image behind the image frame. Anything falling outside the ImageView will be cropped.

Comment: What are your values for the ImageView's layout_width/height?

Comment: They are a static width/height. I'm trying to make thumbnails that are center crops of the original images.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure what the problem is. For me it works just as you're expecting; I've onlt tested it in XML though. Should work the same though.

Comment: The images are shown in full and not cropped. The aspect ratio is preserved, so the image size is actually smaller than what I want. I have a square area I'm defining that they should be cropped to.

Comment: Ok, this is the correct way to do it. I was downloading the images at the wrong size.

Comment: Still it should do it at whatever size. I actually did some more testing and ran into some of the some issues you were having. :( Glad you have it working now, though!